# Maven + IDEA: cannot find String

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying out the workflow where you create and maintain your project primarily in Maven, and the Intellij IDEA project files are derived from that, which seems to be the recommended way these days.

My setup: Windows 7, JDK 11, Maven 3.6.0, IDEA Community 2018.2.6, the latter three all fairly fresh installs, not messed around with, verified as working in their own right.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html followed steps to create a Hello World project, verified it compiles and runs with Maven after adding the project property entries to specify we are not on Java 5 anymore.

Opened the project in IDEA by opening pom.xml and saying yes, this is a project file.

Opened App.java, and references to String are underlined in red: Cannot resolve symbol 'String'.

Tried invalidate caches / restart, no change.

Consensus as far as I can tell is that maven is the top build system and IDEA is the top IDE, so it must be possible to get them to work together. How?

Comment: This sounds like the project does not have a JDK defined since IDEA cannot find java's own classes. IDEA should ask you to define one on the top of the code area.

Comment: it compiles and runs, but it can't find the String class?

Comment: @Stultuske Compiles and runs with command line maven, cannot find the String class in the IDE.

Comment: @f1sh Ah, that was it, thanks! Ctrl-Shift-Alt-S, project settings and specify a JDK there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Project Structure` (by pressing `F4`):

[image]

Check the `SDKs` and `Problems` sections for any error.

Comment: That works, except on my version the shortcut is Ctrl-Shift-Alt-S (or File menu) and different screen layout. Thanks!